# ¿Cómo encontrar la ruta del `User/NombreUsuario` ?con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, rutas

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de Python con manejo de archivos y necesito guardar un archivo dentro de la carpeta `C:\Users\<NombreUsuario>` pero **¿como hago para que mi código pueda encontrar esta ruta? si cada nombre de User es diferente(lo quiero para que se ejecute en diversas máquinas)**

No adjunto código porque no creo que sea necesario

Comment: [`Path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser) o [`Path.home`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) u [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar los métodos que te dejaron en los comentarios que son funcionales o también importar la librería `psutil` y usar el metodo **psutil.users()** para tener los nombres de todos los usuarios de la maquina.

**psutil.users()** devuelve una lista en donde se encuentra información acerca de los usuarios, si solo existe un usuario devuelve algo así:

> [suser(name='usuario1', terminal='pts/2', host='localhost', started=1515272211.0, pid=1689)]

Si existen 2 usuarios algo así:

> [suser(name='usuario1', terminal='pts/2', host='localhost', started=1515272211.0, pid=1689), suser(name='usuario2', terminal='pts/3', host='localhost', started=1515272211.0, pid=2314)]

Puedes observar que primero hay una lista y luego una tupla para cada usuario, entonces para identificar el primer usuario y guardarlo en una variable, tomaremos el primer elemento de la lista devuelta (primera tupla) y posteriormente el primer elemento de la primera tupla (nombre de usuario), por esa razón lo usamos de esta manera -->**usuario = info_usuarios[0][0]**

```py
import psutil

info_usuarios = psutil.users()
usuario = info_usuarios[0][0]

ruta = "C:/Users/" + usuario
print(ruta)
```